# Error 13 when Pasting from another Workbook

Tags: vba, runtime-error, copy-paste

I'm new to VBA, and I've been trying to paste some data from one file into my active file.  Unfortunately, I've been getting error 13 - Type Mismatch.  I've tried changing each of the variable definitions, even declaring them as `Variant`, but nothing helped.  The most relevant part of the code is below, with the error between the asterisks.

```
dim i, j, k, CompShtStartNum, CompShtQty as integer
dim OldFile as variant
dim WCompWS, WCOl, NumEntryCol, ShtName as string
dim InputsSht as worksheet
dim NumEntryColRange, OldEntryCount as range


'Paste data from Entry Label columns into comparison sheets
    'Paste in the data from the old file
        For i = CompShtStartNum To CompShtStartNum + CompShtQty - 1
            ShtName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
            Set OldSht = OldFile.Sheets(ShtName)
            Set OldEntryCount = Range(OldSht.Cells(2, 1), OldSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown))
            For j = 1 To CompShtStartNum - i + 1
                For k = 1 To InputsSht.Range(WCol & 12 + j - 1).Value
                     If OldFile.Sheets(i).Cells(1, k).Value = Sheets(i).Cells(1, k).Value Then
                        ***Sheets(i).Cells(2, k).Resize(OldEntryCount.Rows.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(OldEntryCount.Value)***
                    End If
                Next k
            Next j
       Next i
```

For context, here is the full code:

```
Set OldFile = Application.Workbooks("Old Input File.xlsx")
    Let WCompWS = "E"
    Let WCol = "F"
    Let CompShtStartNum = 2
    Set InputsSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inputs")
    Let CompShtQty = InputsSht.Range(WCompWS & 12, InputsSht.Range(WCompWS & 12).End(xlDown)).Count

'Loop thru each sheet and have the user determine the last column of labels.  Paste result on Inputs sheet.
    For i = CompShtStartNum To CompShtStartNum + CompShtQty - 1
        ShtName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
        Sheets(ShtName).Activate
        NumEntryCol = Application.InputBox("How many columns (from the left-hand side) contain entry labels?" & vbNewLine & "(Examples of entry labels: Library #, Entry #, etc.)" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please type your answer numerically.", ShtName)
        InputsSht.Range(WCol & 12 + i - CompShtStartNum).Value = NumEntryCol
    Next i
    Set NumEntryColRange = InputsSht.Range(WCol & 12, InputsSht.Range(WCol & 12).End(xlDown))
    InputsSht.Activate

'Paste data from Entry Label columns into comparison sheets
    'Paste in the data from the old file
        For i = CompShtStartNum To CompShtStartNum + CompShtQty - 1
            ShtName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
            Set OldSht = OldFile.Sheets(ShtName)
            Set OldEntryCount = Range(OldSht.Cells(2, 1), OldSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown))
            For j = 1 To CompShtStartNum - i + 1
                For k = 1 To InputsSht.Range(WCol & 12 + j - 1).Value
                     If OldFile.Sheets(i).Cells(1, k).Value = Sheets(i).Cells(1, k).Value Then
                        ***Sheets(i).Cells(2, k).Resize(OldEntryCount.Rows.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(OldEntryCount.Value)***
                    End If
                Next k
            Next j
       Next i
```

Any help or suggestions would be very appreciated!!

Comment: BIRDS VIEW: `InputsSht.Activate` and then `Set OldEntryCount = Range(OldSht.Cells(2, 1), OldSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown))` I don't understand it? Shouldn't it be `Set OldEntryCount = OldSht.Range(OldSht.Cells(2, 1), OldSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown))`?

Comment: `OldSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown))` do you mean `xlUp` ?

Comment: @Siddharth, your suggestion to put `OldSht.` in front of `Range` makes sense to me and I tried it out, but unfortunately it didn't change anything.  @Tim, the data I want to pull over in the first iteration is (in this case) located in A2:A7 of the old file's first sheet, so I thought `xlDown` would be right.  For kicks, I just tried `xlUp` and strangely enough, it didn't flag an error.  However, the result was only the value in A2 being pasted into A2:A7 on the active file sheet.  How can I get each of the values in A2:A7 to paste into their respective cells on my active sheet?

Comment: Try this `Sheets(i).Cells(2, k).Resize(OldEntryCount.Rows.Count, 1).Value = OldEntryCount.Value`

Comment: Yes! @Siddharth, that does the trick. Can you or Tim explain to me why it was only pasting the value in A2 before? And why now it doesn't seem to make a visible difference (except in run-time) to use xlUp or xlDown?

Comment: I can answer that but can you see the difference between my line and your line? What is `Application.Transpose` used? What effect could it be having here? ;) Let's see if you can figure it out else I will update my post with an explanation.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like `Application.Transpose` takes a column of values, transposes to be a row of values, then this is pasted into the target. Essentially, it would be pasting the transposition into each row of the target, but since the target is one column wide, only the first value in the transposition (the value in A2) is pasted?  Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, the result was only the value in A2 being pasted into A2:A7 on the active file sheet. How can I get each of the values in A2:A7 to paste into their respective cells on my active sheet?

Try this

```
Sheets(i).Cells(2, k).Resize(OldEntryCount.Rows.Count, 1).Value = _
OldEntryCount.Value
```

Here is a short demonstration. Let's say our worksheet looks like this

[image]

Now lets say we want the values of `A1:A5` in `B1:B5` in `Sheet1`

Simply try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim OldEntryCount As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set OldEntryCount = .Range("A1:A5")

        .Range("B1").Resize(OldEntryCount.Rows.Count, 1).Value = _
        OldEntryCount.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

And you will get the result

[image]