# How to paste a whole array without looping through it in VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have this code which will populate an array

```
Sub rangearray()

    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("G10:G14")

    For Each myCell In Rng
        ReDim Preserve arr(i)
        arr(i) = myCell
        i = i + 1
    Next myCell

    ActiveSheet.Range("H10:H14") = arr()

End Sub
```

Here you can see that the values in the watch window are what has been loaded in

[image]

Except, when I add the array back to the workbook it only pastes back the first element of the array.

[image]

Is it possible to paste the whole array to the worksheet without having to loop through the array?

After taking a look at the link from Sorceri, I have amended to code to use the .Transpose function, so my amended code now look like this:

```
Sub rangearray()

    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5")

    For Each myCell In Rng
        ReDim Preserve arr(i)
        arr(i) = myCell
        i = i + 1
    Next myCell

    ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B5") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need an array for this? See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277994/error-13-when-pasting-from-another-workbook/19280614#19280614)

Comment: Because I want to paste from an array, not from another range

Comment: But isn't that what you are doing? `Range("G10:G14") --> Range("H10:H14")`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will want to use the [transpose worksheet function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196261.aspx).

See below.  You have to assign it to the range's value:

```
Sub rangearray()

Dim arr() As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Dim i As Integer

Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5")

For Each myCell In Rng
    ReDim Preserve arr(i)
    arr(i) = myCell
    i = i + 1
Next myCell

ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B5").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)

End Sub
```

Comment: Bare links should be posted as comments ;) Or you might want to improve upon it? What if the link dies out? its not good for any future users.

Comment: Yeah, flesh the answer out a bit please

Comment: @SiddharthRout  if the link dies out then get mad at MS.  Even if the linked died out, i put the name of the function and if someone cannot use an internet search than by all means they should not be writing code.

Comment: That doesn't mean that you should put a low quality answer ;) I could have downvoted you as per [THIS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199929/guess-i-have-still-not-got-the-hang-of-it) But I chose the 2nd Option (See @juergend's answer)... Letting you know so that you could improve the answer ;)

Comment: Why do you do `ReDim Preserve` here? Do you start with `i=1` or `i=0`?

Comment: @parsecer  Preserve keeps the elements already in the array when dimensioning the upper bounds. Being that we are looping and creating the array dynamically we want to keep the contents previously assigned. (although this is a bad example as we know that the array is 5 elements so we could have declared the array outright).   All arrays in VBA start at index 0 unless you state Option Base 1 at the start of the module which then indicates Arrays start at index 1

Answer (score 20):

As I mentioned in my comment above that you do not need an array to perform the action that you trying to do but still if you want only an array solution then you don't need to go the long way of filling the array in a loop. Directly assign the range's value to the array. It will create a 2D array which you don't need to transpose.

```
Sub rangearray()
    Dim arr
    Dim Rng As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("G10:G14")

        arr = Rng.Value

        .Range("H10").Resize(UBound(arr, 1)).Value = arr
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Another benefit of using this method (as opposed to transpose) is that Application.Transpose has a limit of up arrays up to 2^16 long.  If your array is too big, you will get bad results.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055784/best-workaround-for-vba-transpose-array-length-limit

Comment: Good but this approach works only if the source range is of column orientation. If the source is of row orientation, only the first cell's ("G10") value gets copied to "H10" and below, assuming the argument of `Resize` is changed to `UBound(arr, 2)` .

Answer (score 0):

Just assigned Rng to arr then put back to sheet. it works for me in Excel 2016

```
Sub rangearray()

    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5")

    arr = Rng

    ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B5").Resize(5) = arr

End Sub
```