# vba tranpose type mismatch error

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, transpose

I have been trying to transpose an array to paste records from a ADODB.recordset into an excel row. (The records are stored in a 2D Variant array). However, whenever I try something like the first row of the code below, I get a 13: type mismatch error code. I therefore tried to dig down into seeing exactly where the error lay, and built a simple integer 2d array. It appears that the transpose function can't do this transposition either without throwing a 13 error code. Research online seemed to suggest this error is caused when the number of elements being transposed exceed 64k but this can't be it below. Any thoughts?

```
varRecords = rs2.GetRows(3)     ' rs2 is a ADOBD.Recordset
intNumReturned = UBound(varRecords, 2) + 1
intNumColumns = UBound(varRecords, 1) + 1

For intRow = 0 To intNumReturned - 1
   For intColumn = 0 To intNumColumns - 1
     Debug.Print varRecords(intColumn, intRow)
   Next intColumn
Next intRow

Dim Destination As Range
Set Destination = Range("k1")

Dim i, j As Integer

'Destination.Resize(UBound(varRecords, 2) + 1, UBound(varRecords, 1) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(varRecords)   - COMMENTED OUT BECAUSE IT ERRORS TYPE 13 TYPE MISMATCH


Dim myarr(3, 4) As Integer 
myarr(0, 1) = 4
myarr(2, 4) = 6

Dim myvar As Variant

Set myvar = Application.Transpose(myarr)        ' - ERROR THROWN HERE
```

Comment: remove `Set` keyword: `myvar = Application.Transpose(myarr)`

Comment: You should add more infomration to this question if you are looking for assistance with the first line. Otherwise, the posted answer is correct and should be accepted.  For the commented code, perhaps it will be helpful if you show how `varRecords` is instantiated, assigned, and its dimensions. Also please indicate what specific error message you get on that line.  Cheers.

Comment: Ok, will edit existing question

Comment: As you pull data from ADODB recordset to array, **the reason** for the type mismatch error might be that some *empty* values are stored as `null` in the resulting array. **`Transpose` cannot process nulls**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I get the same error (13:type mismatch). An easy workaround would be to transpose the array yourself:

```
Sub arrTest()
    Dim myarr(3, 4) As Integer
    myarr(0, 1) = 4
    myarr(2, 4) = 6

    Dim myvar As Variant

    ReDim myvar(1 To UBound(myarr, 2), 1 To UBound(myarr, 1))
    For i = 1 To UBound(myvar, 2)
        For j = 1 To UBound(myarr, 1)
            myvar(i, j) = myarr(j, i)
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Edit: Simoco is right, removing the "Set" keyword fixes the problem altogether.

2nd Edit: The following works for me:

```
Destination.Resize(UBound(varRecords, 2) + 1, UBound(varRecords, 1) + 1) = Application.Transpose(varRecords)
```

What kind of error do you receive when executing that first line of code?

Comment: The Simoco soln does solve the 13 error but unfortunately does not solve the error occurring at first line of code (currently commented out at the moment) where there is no set command.

Comment: What do you intend to do with that line exactly? Currently, it seems you are trying to assign an Array to a value (.Value statement on the left side of the equation). This is not possible.

Comment: @MarcZilla you're mistaken. You can absolutely assign an array to an appropriately sized range `.Value`.

Comment: The .value of a range is the content of the range (a number or string, e.g. "1000"). In that case you would be trying to assign an array to a number or string.

Comment: Insane. Transpose function IS to avoid transposing array yourself!

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this same issue, and I'm betting you received the Type Mismatch for the same reason I did. One of your cells contains a string that is greater than 255 characters in length. I can't explain why Transpose can't handle a variant/string > 255, but it doesn't. Looks like an Excel bug.  That's why coding your own transpose function works.

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue and the cause was from NULL's being stored in the array. A quick solve is to replace Null values in the array before transpose.

```
For i = 0 To 17
If IsNull(MetaAy(i, 0)) Then MetaAy(i, 0) = ""
Next i
```

Be careful using UBound if the last field contains a NULL. UBound() shows the array at the length the last non-null value was entered.

Answer (score 5):

I also found the issue to be when an array element is too long. I like @one angry researcher's answer, wanted an array transpose function I could just use. I can't leave a comment, but after fixing some of the loops, I get this:

```
Function transposeArray(myarr As Variant) As Variant
    Dim myvar As Variant
    ReDim myvar(LBound(myarr, 2) To UBound(myarr, 2), LBound(myarr, 1) To UBound(myarr, 1))
    For i = LBound(myarr, 2) To UBound(myarr, 2)
        For j = LBound(myarr, 1) To UBound(myarr, 1)
            myvar(i, j) = myarr(j, i)
        Next
    Next
    transposeArray = myvar
End Function
```

Comment: 0 instead of 1 is not fixing. In Excel you often want array dimensions to start indexing from 1. But you are right, it would be great to get a ready to use function in some of these answers :) I would just change 0's to `Lbound()`

Comment: The more 'ya know! I edited the answer to use `lbound()`. Thanks!

Comment: For it to be a "copy-and-paste function", add 'Dim i, j As Integer'

Answer (score 0):

While I didn't use the "set" I had the error 13.
MarcZilla solution worked for me and is very fast even for transposing very large arrays.
There are intrinsic limitations to my version of excel 2010
They can be found on
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/177991?wa=wsignin1.0