# VBA Macro to extract data from a chart in Excel 2007, 2010, and 2013

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I was sent an Excel sheet that with 4 charts. The data for the charts is in another workbook that was not provided.

Goal: I want to extract the data from the charts using a VBA sub.

Problem: I am having some trouble with "type mismatch." When I try to assign the Variant array `oSeries.XValues` to a Range of cells.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
' 1. Enter the following macro code in a module sheet.
' 2. Select the chart from which you want to extract the underlying data values.
' 3. Run the GetChartValues Sub. The data from the chart is placed in a new worksheet named "ChartName Data".
'
Sub GetChartValues()
    '
    Dim lxNumberOfRows As Long
    Dim lyNumberOfRows As Long
    Dim oSeries As Series
    Dim lCounter As Long
    Dim oWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim oChart As Chart
    Dim xValues() As Variant
    Dim yValues() As Variant
    Dim xDestination As Range
    Dim yDestination As Range


    Set oChart = ActiveChart
    ' If a chart is not active, just exit
    If oChart Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Create the worksheet for storing data
    Set oWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    oWorksheet.Name = oChart.Name & " Data"


    ' Loop through all series in the chart and write there values to
    ' the worksheet.
    lCounter = 1
    For Each oSeries In oChart.SeriesCollection

        xValues = oSeries.xValues
        yValues = oSeries.values

        ' Calculate the number of rows of data. 1048576 is maximum number of rows in excel.
        lxNumberOfRows = WorksheetFunction.Min(UBound(oSeries.xValues), 1048576 - 1)
        lyNumberOfRows = WorksheetFunction.Min(UBound(oSeries.values), 1048576 - 1)

        ' Sometimes the Array is to big, so chop off the end
        ReDim Preserve xValues(lxNumberOfRows)
        ReDim Preserve yValues(lyNumberOfRows)


        With oWorksheet
            ' Put the name of the series at the top of each column
            .Cells(1, 2 * lCounter - 1) = oSeries.Name
            .Cells(1, 2 * lCounter) = oSeries.Name

            Set xDestination = .Range(.Cells(1, 2 * lCounter - 1), .Cells(lxNumberOfRows + 1, 2 * lCounter - 1))
            Set yDestination = .Range(.Cells(1, 2 * lCounter), .Cells(lxNumberOfRows + 1, 2 * lCounter))

            'Assign the x and y data from the chart to a range in the worksheet
             xDestination.value = Application.Transpose(xValues)
             yDestination.value = Application.Transpose(yValues)

            ' This does not work either
            ' .Range(.Cells(2, 2 * lCounter - 1), .Cells(lxNumberOfRows + 1, 2 * lCounter - 1)).value = Application.Transpose(oSeries.xValues)
            ' .Range(.Cells(2, 2 * lCounter), .Cells(lxNumberOfRows + 1, 2 * lCounter)).value = Application.Transpose(oSeries.values)


        End With

        lCounter = lCounter + 1
    Next

    ' Cleanup
    Set oChart = Nothing
    Set oWorksheet = Nothing

End Sub
```

The main issue is the following lines:

```
.Range(.Cells(2, 2 * lCounter - 1), .Cells(lxNumberOfRows + 1, 2 * lCounter - 1)) = Application.Transpose(oSeries.xValues)
.Range(.Cells(2, 2 * lCounter), .Cells(lxNumberOfRows + 1, 2 * lCounter)) = Application.Transpose(oSeries.values)
```

Upon further inspection using the Locals window, I find the following:
[image]

The below code works while the above code does not.

```
Sub Test2()
Dim A(6) As Variant
'A(1) = 1
A(2) = 2#
A(3) = 3#
A(4) = 4#
A(5) = 5#
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(6, 1)).value = Application.Transpose(A)
End Sub
```

**Why doesn't the first piece of code work?**

Looping over many cells is slow in this case (I've tried). Please, don't use a loop unless it is seconds for 1,000,000 element.

Comment: I don't see any problem assigning an array with `Empty` values to a worksheet - are you sure that's the issue ?

Comment: Agree with @TimWilliams, I do not have an issue with `Empty` and outputting to a range.  Might want to add `.Value` to the end of those `.Range()` calls to make explicit what you want.  Sometimes that can be problematic with array output, IIRC.  As a side note, `Resize` is a helpful function when building `Ranges` like this.  Saves a lot of mistakes that can be made using `.Cells` in the middle.  Likely unrelated to your problem though.

Comment: If I assign something else than `Empty` to the 1st element, then I don't have a problem. That is why I am focused on the `Empty`.

When I read into an Array from a range, the size is `(1 to 300, 1 to 1)`. The array I am working with is `(1 to 1048576)` and thus miss a dimension. Is this related to my problem?

Comment: Since that is the maximum number of rows, you might be going out the bottom of the `Worksheet` with `Range` since you are adding 1 additional row to it.  I believe what you're saying about `Empty`, but it's hard to call that the issue since 2 of us say it works fine.  I'm using Excel 2013 for what it's worth.  Does the problem exist if you start in row 1 instead of 2?

Comment: It does not matter if I start from 1 or 2. I do have some logic in my code for dealing with the maximum number of rows. I just didn't show it here for clarity.

Comment: I found the problem! It is the Transpose function. The transpose function has limit on how many values it can handle. More can be found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055784/best-workaround-for-vba-transpose-array-length-limit

Comment: I guess add that as the answer below.  Still not sure how that is affected by you changing the `Empty` values to something else... it's 1048576 values either way.

Comment: Byron, I have to apologize. I went back and tried setting the first value you in the array to zero, `xValues(1) = 0` and then trying to output it to the sheet. It gave me an error. I was wrong and you were right. `Empty` was never causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main cause is the built-in `Transpose` function. `Transpose` can only handle arrays with 2^16 or less elements.

The code below works well. It handles the problem of Transpose function limitation of 2^16 elements. It uses a for loop but the for loop is fast for arrays. For four series and each having 1048576 elements, the Sub took about 10 seconds to run. This is acceptable.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
' 1. Enter the following macro code in a module sheet.
' 2. Select the chart from which you want to extract the underlying data values.
' 3. Run the GetChartValues Sub. The data from the chart is placed in a new worksheet named "ChartName Data".
'
Public Sub GetChartValues()

    Dim lxNumberOfRows As Long
    Dim lyNumberOfRows As Long
    Dim oSeries As Series
    Dim lSeriesCounter As Long
    Dim oWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim oChart As Chart
    Dim xValues() As Variant
    Dim yValues() As Variant
    Dim xDestination As Range
    Dim yDestination As Range


    Set oChart = ActiveChart
    ' If a chart is not active, just exit
    If oChart Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Create the worksheet for storing data
    Set oWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    oWorksheet.Name = oChart.Name & " Data"


    ' Loop through all series in the chart and write their values to the worksheet.
    lSeriesCounter = 1
    For Each oSeries In oChart.SeriesCollection
        ' Get the x and y values
        xValues = oSeries.xValues
        yValues = oSeries.values

        ' Calculate the number of rows of data.
        lxNumberOfRows = UBound(xValues)
        lyNumberOfRows = UBound(yValues)

        ' 1048576 is maximum number of rows in excel. Sometimes the Array is too big. Chop off the end.
        If lxNumberOfRows >= 1048576 Then
            lxNumberOfRows = 1048576 - 1
            ReDim Preserve xValues(lxNumberOfRows)
        End If
        If lyNumberOfRows >= 1048576 Then
            lyNumberOfRows = 1048576 - 1
            ReDim Preserve yValues(lyNumberOfRows)
        End If

        With oWorksheet
            ' Put the name of the series at the top of each column
            .Cells(1, 2 * lSeriesCounter - 1) = oSeries.Name & " X Values"
            .Cells(1, 2 * lSeriesCounter) = oSeries.Name & " Y Values"
            Set xDestination = .Range(.Cells(2, 2 * lSeriesCounter - 1), .Cells(lxNumberOfRows + 1, 2 * lSeriesCounter - 1))
            Set yDestination = .Range(.Cells(2, 2 * lSeriesCounter), .Cells(lxNumberOfRows + 1, 2 * lSeriesCounter))
        End With


        ' Arrays larger than 2^16 will fail with Transpose function. Therefore must manually transpose
        If lxNumberOfRows > 2& ^ 16 Then

            'Assign the x and y data from the chart to a range in the worksheet. Use the ManualTranspose for  2^16 or more elements.
             xDestination.value = ManualTranspose(xValues)
             yDestination.value = ManualTranspose(yValues)
        Else

            'Assign the x and y data from the chart to a range in the worksheet. Use the built-in Transpose for less than 2^16 elements.
            xDestination.value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(xValues)
            yDestination.value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(yValues)
        End If

        lSeriesCounter = lSeriesCounter + 1
    Next

    ' Cleanup
    Set oChart = Nothing
    Set oWorksheet = Nothing

End Sub

' Helper function for when built-in Transpose function cannot be used. Arrays larger than 2^16 must be transposed manually.
Private Function ManualTranspose(ByRef arr As Variant) As Variant
    Dim arrLength As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim TransposedArray() As Variant

    arrLength = UBound(arr)

    ReDim TransposedArray(arrLength, 1)

    For i = 1 To arrLength
        TransposedArray(i, 1) = arr(i)
    Next i

    ManualTranspose = TransposedArray
End Function
```

Comment: Looks good.  Since you're now reduced to iterating all the elements, would  it be simpler to remove the `Empty` elements at the end and use `Transpose` again?

Comment: Byron, sometimes this is true. However, I have found gaps in the data where the array is `Empty` and then there is more data after the empty section. Therefore, to ensure data was not missed, the all of data values in the array by must be checked. Getting rid of the `Empty` values after iterating through the whole array seems like more work then just transposing the whole thing.