# Array values not transposed to cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to learn how to use a dictionary in Excel VBA. The test is to get all values from rows 1-100000 in column A to a dictionary via an array and then write all the values to column B. This works fine until row 34464, the rest of the rows in column B just gets `#N/A`.

Any ideas why?

```
Sub nnn()

'Tools - References - Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim myRow As Long
Dim dicMyDictionary As Scripting.Dictionary
Set dicMyDictionary = New Scripting.Dictionary

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    myArray = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(100000, 1)).Value

    For myRow = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1)
        dicMyDictionary.Add myRow, myArray(myRow, 1)
    Next myRow

    myArray = dicMyDictionary.Items

    .Range("B1").Resize(dicMyDictionary.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(myArray)
    Set dicMyDictionary = Nothing

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: There are limitations when using Transpose: link 1 - [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/177991), link 2 - [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055784/best-workaround-for-vba-transpose-array-length-limit)

Comment: I could not get your code to write anything to column B.  Rather it reported a `Error 13 Type Mismatch` because the Transpose worksheet function has a limit of 65,536 elements in a single dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the limitations of the worksheetfunction `Transpose` (see also the links posted by Paul Bica), you need to assign the elements to the array directly.  The following should work:

```
Option Explicit
Sub nnn()

'Tools - References - Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim myRow As Long
Dim dicMyDictionary As Scripting.Dictionary
Set dicMyDictionary = New Scripting.Dictionary

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    myArray = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(100000, 1)).Value

    For myRow = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1)
        dicMyDictionary.Add myRow, myArray(myRow, 1)
    Next myRow

    ReDim myArray(1 To dicMyDictionary.Count, 1 To 1)
    For myRow = 1 To UBound(myArray, 1)
        myArray(myRow, 1) = dicMyDictionary(myRow)
    Next myRow

    .Range("B1").Resize(dicMyDictionary.Count, 1).Value = myArray
    Set dicMyDictionary = Nothing

End With

End Sub
```