# Run-time error '458' Variable uses an Automation Type supported in Visual Basic on array

Tags: excel, vba

I have a module in Excel VBA that runs a SQL Query and then transposes the array to get it oriented correctly

```
With connRSet
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CursorLocation = 3
    .CursorType = 2
    .Source = "SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(number, 6), shippingStateID, plant " _
        & "FROM manufacturing.shippingjob " _
        & "WHERE (" & orders & ") AND shippingStateID != 3 " _
        & "ORDER BY shippingStateID, number, plant"
    .Open

End With

'Placing recordset in array then transposing it for correct orientation
Dim detailArray As Variant
detailArray = connRSet.GetRows

Dim trueArray As Variant
trueArray = TransposeArray(detailArray)
```

The query runs ok and can output the result set, just oriented the wrong way, so the TransposeArray function flips the recordset. It should be noted I have used this function in other programs and it has worked without a hitch.

```
Function TransposeArray(v As Variant) As Variant
' Transpose dimensions of a 0-based
' multi-dimensional array

Dim X As Long, Y As Long, Xupper As Long, Yupper As Long
Dim tempArray As Variant

Xupper = UBound(v, 2)
Yupper = UBound(v, 1)

ReDim tempArray(Xupper, Yupper)
For X = 0 To Xupper
    For Y = 0 To Yupper
        tempArray(X, Y) = v(Y, X)
    Next Y
Next X

TransposeArray = tempArray

End Function
```

However, when running the code, I get

> Run-time error '458': Variable uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic

This occurs in the line

> tempArray(X, Y) = v(Y, X)

when X = 0 and Y = 1 where v(Y, X) = 1. In the previous iteration v(Y = 0, X = 0) = "152044". I realize these are different data types but both arrays are coded as Variants. Could there be a reason it isn't working in this case when it has in others?

Comment: Instead of re-inventing the wheel with `TransposeArray` you could use [WorksheetFunction.Transpose Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-transpose-method-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to transpose an array.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ that is good for small arrays, but it does have a limit to the number and size of the array.  The method provided here should work for all arrays.

Comment: @ScottCraner Interesting, do you know where I can find the limit? Would be neat to know that. The MSDN sadly doesn't document it. //edit nevermind it seems to be 2¹⁶

Comment: @Pᴇʜ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055784/best-workaround-for-vba-transpose-array-length-limit?lq=1 https://newtonexcelbach.com/2016/01/01/worksheetfunction-transpose-changed-behaviour-in-excel-2013-and-2016/

Comment: My guess is it has something to do with the data and not the code.  The code is fairly mundane and should work without issue in an of itself.

Comment: @ScottCraner Looking at the database, 'number' is marked as nvarchar and does not throw an error when used. 'ShippingStateID' (which does throw the error) and 'plant' are both TINYINT. I will try using CAST in the Select to see if something else works.

Comment: @ScottCraner adding a CAST(XXX as signed integer) worked!