# VBA What is the Shape of Range Variant Array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert a range of variable length into a variant array.  The range will always be one column with a variable number of rows.  Something along these lines Range(B2:B711).

I have been trying to figure out how to iterate through the array but can not figure out how to get this to work.  I can use a for each loop to loop through each element but I can not seem to iterate using a standard for loop.

I've set up the test function below.  Uncommenting any one of the debug.print(month_arr(...)) lines results in the loop halting on index 0 with zero output.

I can not figure out:

- The shape of the array created by month_arr = my_range.Value2
- The correct syntax for accessing the index values of the month_arr
- Why the for each loop can read the array but a standard for loop can not.

If anyone can provide any guidance on what I am doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

```
Function my_test(my_range As Range) As Variant

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim start_row As Integer
    Dim month_arr As Variant
    Dim last_index As Integer
    Dim elem

    month_arr = my_range.Value2

    start_row = my_range.row - 1
    last_index = UBound(month_arr)

    Debug.Print (start_row)
    Debug.Print (last_index)

'    For Each elem In month_arr
'        Debug.Print elem
'        my_test = 1
'    Next elem

    For i = 0 To last_index
        'Debug.Print (month_arr(i))

        'Debug.Print (month_arr(i, 0))
        'Debug.Print (month_arr(i, 1))
        'Debug.Print (month_arr(i, 2))

        'Debug.Print (month_arr(0, i))
        'Debug.Print (month_arr(1, i))
        'Debug.Print (month_arr(2, i))

        Debug.Print ("i: " & i)
        If i >= 10 Then

            'my_test = Return month_arr at index 10
            Exit Function
            End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: When you load an array like that it is a two dimensional array with a base of `1` not `0`.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, thank you for the response.  I'm new to VBA so it never occurred to me that the base would not be zero.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with leaving it a vertical array, just realize that the array base is `1` not `0` when bulk loading:

```
Function my_test(my_range As Range) As Variant

    Dim i As Long
    Dim start_row As Long
    Dim month_arr As Variant
    Dim last_index As Long

    month_arr = my_range.Value2

    start_row = my_range.Row - 1
    last_index = UBound(month_arr, 1)

    Debug.Print start_row
    Debug.Print last_index

    For i = 1 To last_index
        Debug.Print month_arr(i, 1)
        Debug.Print "i: " & i
    Next i
    If i >= 10 Then
        my_test = month_arr(10, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks for the response Scott.

Answer (score 1):

Just transpose the range and then you can refer to each item

EDIT: Note that there's a limit to transposing an array.  but there are some workarounds ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20059207/1521579))

As you mentioned a range of `B2:B711` didn't think about it.

```
Sub test()

    my_test Range("A1:A100")

End Sub

Private Sub my_test(my_range As Range)

    Dim month_arr As Variant

    Dim counter As Long

    month_arr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(my_range.Value2)

    For counter = 1 To UBound(month_arr)

        ' Print item value
        Debug.Print month_arr(counter)

        If counter >= 10 Then
            ' Do something here and exit sub
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Next counter

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Be careful with `Transpose` it has a limit.

Comment: @ScottCraner You're absolutely right. Thanks for the heads up. See my edit.