# WorksheetFunction.Transpose changes data type

Tags: excel, vba, transpose, worksheet-function

I was using `WorksheetFunction.Transpose` in VBA to convert a 1D array of mixed dates/strings into a 2D array for writing to a worksheet.

With my windows regional settings set to `DMY`, the dates being written back were having months/day switched.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been mentioned in this forum with regard to `Dates` being converted to `Strings` by the `WorksheetFunction.Transpose` method.

I looked into this more deeply.

It seems that `WorksheetFunction.Transpose` converts many data types.  The result, after transposition, will be either `Boolean`, `Double`, or `String`

This needs to be taken into account when using this method in VBA.

Here is some code demonstrating the issue:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Sub Tester()
    Dim v, w, i As Long
    
v = Array(CBool(-1), CBool(0), CByte(9), CDbl(1234), CDec(1234), _
            CInt(1234), CLng(1234), CLngPtr(1234), CSng(1234), _
            CCur(123456), #5/1/2015#, "1234")
            
w = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(v)

For i = 1 To UBound(v)
    Debug.Print v(i), TypeName(v(i)), w(i, 1), TypeName(w(i, 1))
Next i


End Sub
```

**debug.print output**

```
True          Boolean       True          Boolean
False         Boolean       False         Boolean
 9            Byte           9            Double
 1234         Double         1234         Double
 1234         Decimal        1234         Double
 1234         Integer        1234         Double
 1234         Long           1234         Double
 1234         Long           1234         Double
 1234         Single         1234         Double
 123456       Currency      $123,456.00   String
01-May-15     Date          01-05-2015    String
1234          String        1234          String
```

**EDIT** Another issue with `WorksheetFunction.Transpose`

- Given a 1D array
- The upper bound of the first dimension of the transposed array will be given by the formula `Ubound(1D_array) mod 2^16`
- Only the **first** `uBound(1D_array) mod 2^16` elements will be returned to the transposed array.

  - Therefore if the 1D array has a ubound of 65537, the transposed array will only contain a single item (the first item in the original array)
  - No error message will be returned.

    - I believe the lack of an error message and this behavior started with Excel 2013.  I recall earlier versions would return an error message in this situation.

Comment: So what's the workaround? Create the 2nd array manually and loop through to populate?

Comment: @jamheadart That's the only solution of which I am aware if you are using a datatype other than string, double or Boolean in the primary array.  You could store dates as doubles, though, and the values won't be changed on transposition.

Comment: If initial array is being populated from a date range the you can try `Range.Value2` instead of `Range.Value`. It preserves underlying value.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij Yes, as I wrote, that would store the dates as doubles.

Comment: @VBasic2008 did you see results that don't match up with what I posted?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ListBox in memory for transposing without the usage of Transpose and the DataTypes stay intact:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Sub Tester2()
    Dim v, w, i As Long
    
v = Array(CBool(-1), CBool(0), CByte(9), CDbl(1234), CDec(1234), _
            CInt(1234), CLng(1234), CLngPtr(1234), CSng(1234), _
            CCur(123456), #5/1/2015#, "1234")
            
w = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(v)

For i = 1 To UBound(v)
    Debug.Print v(i), TypeName(v(i)), w(i, 1), TypeName(w(i, 1))
Next i
   
    With CreateObject("New:{8BD21D20-EC42-11CE-9E0D-00AA006002F3}")
    'Listbox always Base 0
        .List = v
         w = .List 'Now 2-dim with correct typenames, use .column for transpose Row-column)
    End With

For i = 1 To UBound(v)
    Debug.Print v(i), TypeName(v(i)), w(i - 1, 0), TypeName(w(i - 1, 0))
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but my reason for posting this was to point out the problem I came across, so others would be aware of it. There are any number of workarounds -- but if you don't know it might happen, you won't employ them and wind up having to deal with seemingly inexplicable errors.  I had not thought of the `ListBox` method, but it seems to work.  However, on a data sample of 100,000 dates, the `ListBox` method takes 3-4x longer than the simple loop.  (It also takes longer with the original data sample).