# Transpose dynamic range Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Having 25 columns and n number rows in sheet Input_Excel as in the image "DATA" and transposing the same into another sheet as in the image "Output" in my requited specific format. My code is working perfectly when the input_excel having minimal data and giving expected output where as the data being more than 2600 is giving bad output as in the image "Wrong"

I am hanging and struggling a lot to fix the issue. Please help me to find out the problem in my below code. Is there any maximum limit in handling arrays in excel VBA?
Correct me if am dealing any wrong method/calling. Will be a great help and thanks in advance.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim toWs As Worksheet
Dim vDB, vR()
Dim strShName As Variant
Dim r As Long, i As Long, n As Long, lastRow As Long, cc As Long, req_id As String
Dim k As Integer, j As Integer
Dim sc As Range, lr As Long, lc As Long, rg As Range, myRange As Range

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set ws = Sheets("Input Excel")
Set sc = ws.Range("A1")
lr = sc.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
lc = sc.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

strShName = ActiveSheet.Name

If strShName = "Data" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Data").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If


Sheets.Add.Name = "Data"

Columns("A:c").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

Range("A1").Select

Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Set toWs = Sheets("Data") '<~~ Result Sheet

ws.Activate
Range("D1:Y1").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
Range("A1").Select
toWs.Activate

vDB = ws.Range(sc, ws.Cells(lr, lc)).Value

r = UBound(vDB, 1)
cc = ws.Range(sc, ws.Cells(lr, lc)).Columns.Count

For i = 2 To r
    If vDB(i, 1) <> "" Then ' row
        For j = 4 To cc
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To cc, 1 To n)
                For k = 1 To 3
                    vR(k, n) = vDB(i, k)
                Next k
                vR(4, n) = vDB(1, j)
                vR(5, n) = vDB(i, j)
        Next j
    End If
Next i
With toWs
    .UsedRange.Offset(1).Clear
    .Range("A2").Resize(n, 10) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
End With

Range("A3:C3").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial

Range("A1").Value = "Sales Org"
Range("B1").Value = "Soldto"
Range("C1").Value = "TE Part Number"
Range("D1").Value = "Demand_Date"
Range("E1").Value = "Values"

toWs.Select

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set myRange = Range("E2:E" & lastRow)

myRange.Select
    On Error GoTo eh
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
eh:
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set myRange = Range("d2:d" & lastRow)
Range("J1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(FIND(""."",R[1]C[-6],1),0)"
Range("J1").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False

If Range("J1").Value > 0 Then
    myRange.Select
    Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=True
End If

Range("J1").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("E2").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1"=
DAY(RC[-1])&""/""&MONTH(RC[-1])&""/""&YEAR(RC[-1])"

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set myRange = Range("E2:E" & lastRow)

myRange.Select
Selection.FillDown
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Range("D1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("E1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("D:D").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Range("f2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-5]=""NA"",RC[-5],IF(LEN(RC[-5])=
2,CONCAT(""00"",RC[-5]),IF(LEN(RC[-5])=3,
CONCAT(0,RC[-5]),IF(LEN(RC[-5])=1,CONCAT(""000"",RC[-5]),RC[-5]))))"

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set myRange = Range("F2:F" & lastRow)
myRange.Select
Selection.FillDown
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

myRange.Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A2").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

Columns("F:f").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Dim v As Integer

Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Range("A:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit

req_id = InputBox("Please enter request ID which is generated in your 
application")

If req_id = "" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Data").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
Sheets("SaveFile").Select
End If
Range("F1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Case_ID"

Range("F2").Select
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set myRange = Range("F2:F" & lastRow)
myRange.Value = req_id

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set myRange = Range("A1:F" & lastRow)
myRange.Select

Dim t As Integer

If t = 0 Then
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes)
tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium15"
End If

t = 1

Set myRange = Range("A2:B" & lastRow)

myRange.Replace What:="NA", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False


Range("D1").Value = "Demand_Date"


Dim DTAddress As String
DTAddress = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=DTAddress & req_id & 
"_Upload_LTF_Monthly", FileFormat:=6

MsgBox "Please check file is saved in your desktop and upload the same 
desktop saved file"

ws.Activate
Range("D1:Y1").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"
Range("A1").Select
toWs.Activate

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'ActiveWorkbook.Close False
End Sub
```

**DATA**

[image: DATA]

**Output**

[image: Output]

**Wrong**

[image: Wrong]

Comment: `Transpose` has a limit of about 65k items I think.

Comment: is that seriously? How can I do it then? OMG. The entire output is gone mad when the input is more than 2600

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055784/best-workaround-for-vba-transpose-array-length-limit

Comment: Take a look at Power Query.

Comment: may i get any reference for power query?

Comment: Sure. Just do an Internet Search for `Power Query` and you'll see links to the MS documentation along with another 430,000,000 or so references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Transpose Data Range Using Arrays

- Adjust the values in the constants section (`Source`, `Target` and `Other`).
- I've added the headers to be copied to column "H". If you don't want them copied, remove the 3rd element (`, "H"`) in `tgtCols` and delete the line `Target(2)(k, 1) = Source(1, j)`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub transposeDataOnly()
    
    ' Source
    Const srcName As String = "Input_Excel"
    Const srcFirstCell As String = "A1"
    Const srcFirstCol As Long = 3
    ' Target
    Const tgtName As String = "Data"
    Dim tgtCols As Variant
    tgtCols = VBA.Array("C", "E", "H") ' 'VBA' ensures zero-based.
    Const tgtFirstRow As Long = 2
    ' Other
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    
    ' Write values from Source Range to Source Array.
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Set src = wb.Worksheets(srcName)
    Dim Source As Variant
    Source = src.Range(srcFirstCell).CurrentRegion.Value
    
    ' Define Jagged Target Array.
    Dim ubC As Long: ubC = UBound(tgtCols)
    Dim Target As Variant: ReDim Target(0 To ubC)
    Dim ubS1 As Long: ubS1 = UBound(Source, 1)
    Dim ubS2 As Long: ubS2 = UBound(Source, 2)
    Dim Help As Variant
    ReDim Help(1 To (ubS1 - 1) * (ubS2 - srcFirstCol), 1 To 1)
    Dim j As Long ' Columns Array Element Counter, Source Array Columns Counter
    For j = 0 To ubC
        Target(j) = Help
    Next j
    
    ' Write values from Source Array to arrays of Jagged Target Array.
    Dim i As Long ' Source Array Rows Counter
    Dim k As Long ' Arrays of Jagged Target Array Rows Counter
    For i = 2 To ubS1
        If Not IsEmpty(Source(i, srcFirstCol)) Then
            For j = srcFirstCol + 1 To ubS2
                If Not IsEmpty(Source(i, j)) Then
                    k = k + 1
                    Target(0)(k, 1) = Source(i, srcFirstCol) ' TE Part Number
                    Target(1)(k, 1) = Source(i, j)           ' Values
                    Target(2)(k, 1) = Source(1, j)           ' Headers
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Write values from Jagged Target Array to Target Range.
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Set tgt = wb.Worksheets(tgtName)
    'tgt.Cells.ClearContents
    For j = 0 To ubC
        tgt.Cells(tgtFirstRow, tgtCols(j)).Resize(k).Value = Target(j)
    Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: awesome code. just did the whole expectation. Grateful thanks!!