# Arrays in Excel VBA. At some point it puts NA instead of the value

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, simulation

I am trying to make a simple simulation in Excel VBA in which we roll two dices. What is the probability of getting "1"+"2" or "1"+"3"?

This is my code:

```
 Sub ProbabilityMeyerArray()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ArrayDices(1 To 100000, 1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim ArrayResult(1 To 100000) As Variant
    
    'Simulation
    For i = 1 To 100000
        ArrayDices(i, 1) = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 6)
        ArrayDices(i, 2) = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 6)


        If (ArrayDices(i, 1) = 1 And ArrayDices(i, 2) = 3) _
            Or (ArrayDices(i, 1) = 1 And ArrayDices(i, 2) = 2) _
            Or (ArrayDices(i, 1) = 3 And ArrayDices(i, 2) = 1) _
            Or (ArrayDices(i, 1) = 2 And ArrayDices(i, 2) = 1) Then
            
            ArrayResult(i) = 1
            
        Else
            ArrayResult(i) = 0
        End If
    Next i
    
    
    'print the values to cells
    Range("A1:B100000").Value = ArrayDices
    Range("C1:C100000").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ArrayResult)
    
    'Calculate the probability
    Probability = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ArrayResult) / 100000
    
    MsgBox "The Probability is " & Probability
    
End Sub
```

The problem is that when I print the values from arrays to the cells, then in column C I have 0 and 1 (as it should be), but then from row 34465 I get NA. Here is a screenshot:

https://ibb.co/7jsjjJC

So, for some reason it starts putting NA instead of 0 and 1. The calculation does not work properly either, because the probability is too low, and I guess this is because it only counts the first 34464 zeros and ones, while dividing with 100 000. Can you help me understand what is wrong here? It seems to be a problem with (my understanding of) arrays, since I can run a similar simulation without arrays (by simply using cells), and it works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what do you get if you do `debug.print   ArrayResult(34465)`?

Comment: If `transpose` is the problem as @RaymondWu said (the limit is around 65k I think) then you can just do that `Dim ArrayResult(1 To 100000, 1 to 1) As Variant` which declares your array as a 100000 rows x 1 column and then change the code accordingly where needed: `ArrayResult(i,1) = 1` and `ArrayResult(i,1) = 0` and `Range("C1:C100000").Value = ArrayResult`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best workaround for VBA Transpose array length limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055784/best-workaround-for-vba-transpose-array-length-limit)

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked when I removed the transpose function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RaymondWu said in the comments, the problem is that the `Transpose` function has a limit to the length of the array it can manipulate. This limit is somewhere between 65k and 66k columns.

Indeed, your code will run as expected for 65k iterations.

You can easily avoid using `transpose` and to be honest I don't see the reason to use it in the first place.

Instead of declaring your array as `Dim ArrayResult(1 To 100000) As Variant` which by default makes it `1 row x 100000 columns`, you can declare it as so:

```
Dim ArrayResult(1 To 100000, 1 To 1) As Variant
```

This will make it `100000 rows x 1 columns`, which can now be written in a column in excel easily like so:

```
Range("C1:C100000").Value = ArrayResult
```

Of course you will also need to change the code accordingly where needed:

```
 ArrayResult(i,1) = 1
            
        Else
            ArrayResult(i,1) = 0
```

A few other tips:

1. Always use `Option Explicit` at the very top of the code. It makes the declaration of variables mandatory and it helps to avoid mistakes
2. Always use explicit references. When referencing `Ranges` the best practice is to define the worksheet to which they belong e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C100000").Value = ArrayResult`

Comment: Thanks for confirming my guess! I was out and couldn't be sure that's the real reason so I deleted my comment.

Comment: @Stavron Jon  i am facing similar issue only difference is my string array is dynamic size (one dimensional) 1 col and multtiple rows
i split the string to create array and then Application.Transpose(myarr) to range 
for eg if my array size is 80k then after 15k it print #N/A. upto 15k it prints proper values