# Array reset in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Erase to clear all elements in array. It is working fine but what I want is to reset the array to blank in loop so that every time it get data for that row and paste in the transpose. I am facing transpose limit issue so want to do one line at a time. How can I make sure every time in for loop I have new row data ONLY in my Vr(). in below is it making row data as empty and then append new row data.

```
For i = 2 To r
    For j = 3 To c
    Dim Vr() As Variant
   ' Erase vR
        If vDB(i, j) <> "" And vDB(1, j) <> "name" And vDB(1, j) <> "COMMENTS" And vDB(1, j) <> "" Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve Vr(1 To 5, 1 To n)
            For k = 1 To 2
                Vr(k, n) = vDB(i, k)
            Next k
            Vr(5, n) = vDB(i, j)
            Vr(3, n) = vDB(1, j)
            Vr(4, n) = wsDesign.Cells(37, j + 1).Interior.Color
        End If
    Next j
        With wsUploadDPK
        Cells.Resize(n, 5) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Vr)
        End With
        'ReDim Vr(1 To 5, 1 To n)
         Erase Vr()           


Next i
End With
```

Comment: Why don't you do the tranpose manually at the end before writing to the sheet? [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055784/best-workaround-for-vba-transpose-array-length-limit) if you insist to reset the array everytime then you need to assign `n` back to 0 when you `Erase Vr`

Comment: Thanks for reply. My data is huge and excel has transpose limitations, so I am doing it rows.. latter I will change the logic to batches. hope this clear the point. Code is working fine only problem is it place blank in all cells. I want my Vr() to reset to hold new row value.

Comment: I know tranpose has a limit which is why i suggested you tranpose it manually so you can write to the sheet only once. If you want to do in batches then you need to get the last row before writing to the sheet and refer your cell to something like `Cells(lastRow +1,1).Resize(n, 5)` @AndrewD

Comment: Not clear on one thing. What do you mean by "tranpose it manually"? this is code which read a table and do the transpose each line.

Comment: So if i understand your issue correctly, you can't use transpose on the whole array originally because there are too many rows so instead of using the transpose function, declare another array with the dimension flipped (e.g. `ReDim newArr(1 to n, 1 to 5)`) then do a `For` loop and transfer the value from the original array to the new array (`newArr(y, x) = Vr(x, y)`). That way you have transposed the array without facing the function's limitation. @AndrewD