# Not able to copy data from Excel sheet to array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, transpose

I am trying to copy data from excel to an array, the last used row can be the limit of the excel row (1048576). It is able to copy 65535 data rows only. Could someone help me on this?

```
    Dim firstRowData As Integer: firstRowData = 2
    Dim firstColumnData As Integer: firstColumnData = 1
    Dim LastUsedRowData As LongPtr: LastUsedRowData = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    Dim lastcolumnData As LongPtr: lastcolumnData = sht.Cells(firstRowData, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    Dim rangeSelection As Range, arraystoreMasterData() As Variant
    Set rangeSelection = Application.Range(Cells(firstRowData, firstColumnData), Cells(LastUsedRowData, lastcolumnData))
    arraystoreMasterData = Application.Transpose(rangeSelection)
```

Comment: There are some good ideas here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055784/best-workaround-for-vba-transpose-array-length-limit although more focused on 1 X N arrays.

Comment: You can get the values in the array in this simple way: `arrastoreMasterData = rangeSelection.Value`. Do you really want to transpose, so e.g. 100k rows become 100k columns, and what for?

Comment: Transpose can't handle that many elements. Range.Value should still get you a (1-based) 2D variant array with everything there is though.

Comment: Also, use `Long` for all your row and column variables.   Neither `Integer` nor `LongPtr` are appropriate types for this use

Comment: If you are going to `Transpose`, you cannot use `Application.Transpose`.  That function will only transpose the last 65,535 elements.  You'll have to Transpose item by item into a new array.  But why transpose at all?