# Faster way to read XML nodes into Excel

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I am reading in a .xml file into excel and pasting the nodes into cells, but it seems to be pretty slow for a simple process (~20 second for 500 cells). It there a way to make this VBA code faster? It seems like there should be a way to avoid using a loop but I am not very familiar with VBA code.

```
Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
oXMLFile.Load (File)

Dim SN_Node As IXMLDOMNode
' Update Serial Number
i = 1
Set ColNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/Signal/SN_")
For Each SN_Node In ColNodes
  Range("I" & i).Value = SN_Node.Text
  i = i + 1
Next
```

Comment: If you're interested in feedback on any & all aspects of your code (*including* performance), then this would belong on [codereview.se]. I would **strongly** recommend including the actual procedure though, because a good code review post is always better with as much context as possible (e.g. where's that `File` coming from?). Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the info on Code Review. I didn't know about that. The file loaded is just an .xml file that is output from a software program we are using and we are trying to get some information from that file into excel.

Comment: Try saving the data to an array and paste the value to cells. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300555/paste-vba-array

Comment: Thanks. I switched to pasting the array and now it's at a satisfactory speed. Less than 1/10 of a second.

Answer (score 0):

A very important rule experienced VBA coders will tell you: Never update, read or reference cells in a loop. Always use arrays. myArray = Range("myRange") now loop thru myArray. In your case you'd dim an array. And perhaps have to use redim preserve since you may not know size. To output the array you choose a single cell and use the resize function. Range("A1").resize(ubound(myArray), ubound(myArray, 2) = myArray. Now you hold lightening in your hands.