# how to insert array list into table?

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if there is a faster way to insert a list of values into a table object. The method i'm using goes like this:

1) Clear the old data from table

2) find add in new date values to the table and letting the table formulas auto-populate.

The problem right now is that this process is incredibly slow as i have about 7 tables and 4k+ dates to populate.

Ordinarily if it's just pasting the values, excel works incredibly fast. But when it comes to table objects, it gets a lot slower for some reason.

I think there's a way to do this a lot faster by manipulating the table object but i haven't had any luck so far.

```
*table1
     1          2       3       4       5       6
 A   Date       1D      2D      3D      4D      5D
 B   1/1/2016   Formula Formula Formula Formula Formula
 C   2/1/2016   Formula Formula Formula Formula Formula
 D   3/1/2016   Formula Formula Formula Formula Formula
 E   4/1/2016   Formula Formula Formula Formula Formula
 F   5/1/2016   Formula Formula Formula Formula Formula
 G   6/1/2016   Formula Formula Formula Formula Formula
 H   7/1/2016   Formula Formula Formula Formula Formula

Dim ws(), datelist() As Variant
For i = 1 To UBound(ws)
    For j = 1 To UBound(datelist)
        Sheets(CStr(ws(i))).Cells(j + 1, 1) = datelist(j)
    Next j
Next i
```

*ws() refers to array where i store worksheet names

*datelist() refers to the dates i want to paste into the cells.

not sure if my description of the problem is clear enough.

Comment: You might want to disable auto calculation and screenupdate before this old data removal and adding new data. What type of data is in `datelist(j)`? If really formula you can paste the formula (**FormulaR1C1** style) to the table column after all dates added.

Comment: this above process is part of a bigger subroutine, the usual calculations, alerts and screen updates etc have already been turned off. the values in datelist(j) are dates, but they are stored as string. 

the formulas auto-populated in the tables are pretty long and referenced to different stuff for different tables, so i would prefer to take advantage of the auto-populate function instead of coding multiple subroutines to populate or calculate the values.

Comment: Done a quick search, does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300555/paste-vba-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a quick search brought up [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300555/paste-vba-array).

To apply it to your case, instead of: -

```
For i = 1 To UBound(ws)
    For j = 1 To UBound(datelist)
        Sheets(CStr(ws(i))).Cells(j + 1, 1) = datelist(j)
    Next j
Next i
```

Use: -

```
For i = 1 To UBound(ws)
    Sheets(CStr(ws(i))).Range("A" & j + 1 & ":A" & j + (1 + UBound(datelist))) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(datelist)
Next i
```

Comment: hi, thanks! your formula works after removing the "j"s. however, there seems to be something wrong with dates that ended up in the table. Some of them seems to be the wrong format or texts, resulting in the formulas in the table not working. is there a way to format the dates while using Transpose?

Comment: it's alright, i've solved the formatting issue. thanks a lot!!