# How to loop through my variant array for count followed by calculation?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have created a variant array list of unique items in Sheet1 from master sheet (Sheet3). Now I am not sure how to copy each item in my array and paste it in sheet4 in column A and a count of that item from sheet "January" next to it in column B. If I can do that, I can then perform some calculation. Your help will be greatly appreciated

I'm basically trying to build Management Information stats, getting count of items we manage and then work out the percentage of that completed on time.

here's what I have done so far to get a variant array list.

```
Sub PopulatingArrayVariable_v3()

Dim myarray() As Variant
Dim DataRange As range
Dim Cell As range
Dim x As Long
Dim iReport As Integer

Dim lastRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

lastRow = Sheets("Sheet3").range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Sheets("Sheet3")

    .range("D2:D" & lastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, 
copytorange:=Sheets("Sheet1").range("A1"), Unique:=True

End With

Set DataRange = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange


For Each Cell In DataRange.Cells
ReDim Preserve myarray(x)
myarray(x) = Cell.Value
x = x + 1
Next Cell
For x = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)
Debug.Print myarray(x)
Next x

iReport = WorksheetFunction.countif(Sheets("January").range("C6:C100"), 
myarray(6))

Sheets("Sheet4").Activate
range("A2") = myarray(6)
range("B2") = iReport

//do calculation in % and rounded to 0 decimal point

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


End Sub
```

here's example how I want the end table to look like

```
Items                   Count
EMT - Pre Production     4
EMT - Pre Production     5
EMT - Production         10
EMT - Post Production    1
EPT - Pre Production     20
EPT - Production         10
EPT - Post Production    5
AIFMD  - Pre Production  25
AIFMD  - Production      12
AIFMD  - Post Production 12
```

Comment: For count, I would suggest that you just use a formula in column **B** as you already have a unique list (you could use `CountIf` as you have done in your code). To paste an array to your range, use [Transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300555/paste-vba-array)

Comment: Why not use a pivot table?

Comment: thanks. the countif line of code i've used will be lenthly for current array lists contain 97 items. Need this in a loop so it's dynamic and I am not really after count but using this count to work out the percentage over total count of items with prefix say EMT.