# Paste array to range paste only the first value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to paste Array values into a range but it does only paste in range the first value.

```
Dim Array1()

For i = 0 to 9
   ReDim Preserve Array1
   Array1(i)= Int((6 * Rnd) + 1)
Next

ws.Range("A1").Value = Array1
```

output :

[image]

Am I doing wrong something ?

Comment: Since you know the array dimension(s) you should declare as a 2D array, with the appropriate dimensions and fill it on the right dimension. `ReDim Preserve` used often is a kind of memory stress...

Comment: @FaneDuru Hi, thank you for your feedbacks. I had to use `Resize` to get this working

Comment: `Resize` must be used, anyhow... I will post an answer only to see what I wonted suggesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to redimension the array correctly and then transpose it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim Array1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    
    '~~> Change to respective sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    For i = 0 To 9
        ReDim Preserve Array1(i) '<~~ increment by i
        Array1(i) = Int((6 * Rnd) + 1)
    Next
    
    '~~> Store in the worksheet
    ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Array1) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Array1)
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you I saw[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19301252/11167163) but wasn't working since the `Transpose` is missing in the last row of your code

Comment: Yes that is because in that link it is a 2D array. Try the above code. it works.

Answer (score 3):

Please, try the next way, in order to fill an already dimensioned 2D array, easy to drop its content in a range:

```
Sub fill2DArray()
  Dim Array1(1 To 10, 1 To 1), ws As Worksheet, i As Long
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For i = 0 To 9
       Array1(i + 1, 1) = Int((6 * Rnd) + 1)
    Next

 ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Array1), UBound(Array1, 2)).value = Array1
End Sub
```

`Transpose` has some limitations when used on large ranges.

The next version is your corrected code, but avoiding using `ReDim Preserve` for each iteration, which stresses the system memory if used too often:

```
Sub fill1DEfficient()
    Dim Array1(), i As Long, ws As Worksheet, itNo As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    itNo = 10 'number of iterations
    ReDim Array1(itNo - 1)
    For i = 0 To itNo - 1
       Array1(i) = Int((6 * Rnd) + 1)
    Next
   ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Array1) + 1, 1).value = Application.Transpose(Array1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting trick too

Comment: And your code could avoid `Redim Preserve`... Using `Redim` before the loop. I will edit the answer to show it.

Answer (score 1):

### One-Column Array to One-Column Range

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub WriteArrayToOneColumnRange()
    
    Const rCount As Long = 10 ' Number of Elements (rows in this case)
    Const rndMin As Long = 1
    Const rndMax As Long = 6
    
    ' Define the 2D one-based one-column array.
    Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim r As Long ' Element (Row) Counter
    
    ' Populate the array.
    For r = 1 To rCount
        Data(r, 1) = Int(((rndMax - rndMin + 1) * Rnd) + rndMin)
        'Debug.Print Data(r, 1)
    Next r
    
    ' Write the array values to a one-column range starting in 'A1'.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' be more specific
    ws.Range("A1").Resize(rCount).Value = Data

End Sub
```