# how to write from an array in Access to an Excel Range

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a data structure (array) in Access - 6 columns and 10 rows.

I'm trying to write to a range in Excel ie B3:G12.

I'm getting tied up in loops, literally.

```
For j = 0 to ubound(varArray,1)

     For i = 0 to ubound(varArray)

          For each xlCell in wksheet.range("B3:G12")

               xlCell.Value = varArray(i,j)

          Next xlCell

     Next i

Next j
```

This I'm struggling with as the 2 loops work in different ways.  The xlCell loop goes across and then down.

The array loop also goes across but then we switch lanes as it were.

I can't get the xlCell loop to advance at all.

Can someone help?

tintedsepia

Comment: You can paste the array straight into excel, for example  https://www.educba.com/vba-transpose/  and this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300555/how-to-paste-a-whole-array-without-looping-through-it-in-vba

Comment: Doesn't `wksheet.Range("B3:G12").Value = varArray` work?

Comment: @VBasic2008 suggestion works, no looping. But why is an array involved? Could a recordset and CopyFromRecordset method be used?